# How to avoid downtime when resizing virtual machines

Tags: linux, virtualization

Many IaaS provider offer dynamic upgrade/downgrade of RAM and cores.

Usually a Linux VM has to be rebooted to apply these changes.

Sometimes, things like VMware tools or other guest services are well integrated so the *upgrades* to resources are immediately available, but the downgrades still need reboot.

How can I solve this issue, so that when downgrading resources I do not have to reboot my guests?

Comment: I've edited this question so that it will be re-opened. Asking for a specific distro or tool is generally considered shopping and is off-topic. Asking how to solve the actual problem (which is what I've edited into the question) is OK.

Comment: @MDMarra, that's exactly my point! TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With libvirt + KVM on RHEL6 (and presumably others), you can do this with the virsh commands `setmem` and `setvcpus`.

The trick is that you have to set the maximum possible values in the permanent config before you boot the guest.  There is a flag for this on `setvcpus`; for memory you need to say `setmaxmem` instead (great UI there).  Then you can scale them up and down on-the-fly within the range in the config.

For linux guests, it hotplugs the resources to/from the guest.  For windows guests, for memory it tells windows it has the full maximum size always.  However, it will use the balloon driver to hold back any memory you take away.  Not sure about VCPU on windows guests.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally if you're dealing with constant or on-demand scale-up scale-down of individual nodes outside of a maintenance window, a reboot shouldn't matter to you. Your architecture should be fault tolerant, clustered, and/or load balanced so that the loss of a node during resizing doesn't impact anything. This is the kind of thing that Heroku and other PaaS providers do transparently. If you're building your own PaaS out of your IaaS resources, you should strongly consider a similar model.

Additionally, many architectures employ a strategy where nodes in a given tier of an application are a fixed size and entire guest instances are spun up or down as needed rather than resizing individual hosts.

I think you're approaching this the wrong way by changing the guest resource assignments to scale. What you should be doing to making the application scalable in a way that entire guests can be provisioned or destroyed as needed rather than fiddling with RAM or CPU on individual web front-ends or database servers.

Comment: To operate on number of VM's is the correct way to scale on mid-to-big infrastructures. But on little/tiny infrastructures (like 1 or 2 VM's) using applications not designed for cluster this can be the only way  to take advantages of low prices.

Comment: If you only have one or two VMs, why are you constantly resizing them? In that case you would usually size it as a traditional server with capacity to handle 90th percentile traffic.

Comment: You might have 20 or 30 or 50 VMs, but they may not be all running the same application, as you assumed. You're certainly right that fiddling with one or two VMs all the time is unlikely to be productive, but I can imagine circumstances where this would be handy.

Answer (score 2):

If speaking of VMware, online RAM and CPU *decreases* are not supported operations. This is not possible without VM downtime.